# A phrase for "As the opportunity arises and its mutually convenient"?

Tags: phrase-requests

In my course syllabus I have office hours.  However, I am happy to answer student questions if we run into each other in the hall, or if they drop by my office when I am in.  However, between switching offices in buildings and a slew of committee meetings I can't say (other than my office hours) exactly when and where I can be found.

I would like a succinct phrase that conveys that my office hours are "Mondays 9-12, Tuesday 2-5 and whenever you and I happen to run into each other and it's convenient for both us to chat and you have a question".

The phrase "Mondays 9-12, Tuesday 2-5 and whenever you can find me" suggests that I am playing hide and seek.

The phrase "Mondays 9-12, Tuesday 2-5 and by mutual convenience" doesn't quite sound right to me, and not very welcoming.

Suggestions?

Comment: '...and at other times as convenient'?

Comment: You could  add "If you meet me at other times, you are welcome to ask if I have time to talk" after the statement of office hours.

Answer (score 1):

I think "**by flexible appointment**" would also cover a random, mutually convenient meeting. This might be a workable succinct phrase to use.

Answer (score 0):

...Tuesday 2-5, or as able...Tuesday 2-5, or as we may meet.(either phrase implying that an acceptable alternative is to meet however we may happen to catch up with each other).

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Please include sources in your answer to improve its quality.